# Error when reading a two-dimensional table

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to create an infinite game field by connecting the opposite edges of the field. I get the following error:

> Error: attempting to index field '?' (a nil value)

The error is on the line in bold. As far as I understand, the array *field* does not contain any values when called in function *drawField()* despite it was filled with zeros in function *clearField()*. How can I fix the array so it keeps its values outside *clearField()*?

```
local black = 0x000000
local white = 0xFFFFFF

local field = {} 
local function clearField()
  for gx=1,displayWidth do
    if gx==displayWidth then
      field[1] = field[displayWidth+1]
    end
    field[gx] = {}
    for gy=1,displayHeight-3 do
      if gy==displayHeight-3 then
        field[gx][1] = field[gx][displayHeight-2]
      end
      field[gx][gy] = 0
    end
  end
end

--Field redraw
local function drawField()
  for x=1, #field do
    for y=1,x do
      **if field[x][y]==1 then**
        display.setBackground(white)
        display.setForeground(black)
      else
        display.setBackground(black)
        display.setForeground(white)
      end
      display.fill(x, y, 1, 1, " ")
    end
  end
end

-- Program Loop
clearField()
while true do
  local lastEvent = {event.pullFiltered(filter)}
  if lastEvent[1] == "touch" and lastEvent[5] == 0 then
    --State invertion
    if field[lastEvent[3]][lastEvent[4]]==1 then
      field[lastEvent[3]][lastEvent[4]] = 0
    else
      field[lastEvent[3]][lastEvent[4]] = 1
    end
    drawField()
  end
end
```

*display* and *event* variables are libraries.
The program was run with *displayWidth* = 160 and *displayHeight* = 50

Comment: @BhaskaraArani what is wrong with the question? beside the lack of any debuggin attempts I'd say this questions is very good or at least much better than the average.. he explains what he's trying to do, he provides reproducable code, it is formatted well. please be more specific with your critique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`field[1] = field[displayWidth+1]` is equivalent to `field[1] = nil` as you never assigned a value to `field[displayWidth+1]`

Run this to see for yourself:

```
clearField()
print(field[1])
for k,v in pairs(field) do print(v[1]) end
```

So in your outer loop you create 10 entries for field but in the 10th run you delete `field[1]` which later causes the observed error as you're trying to inxex field[1] in `if field[x][y]==1 then`

You could implement a __index metamethodt to get a somewhat circular array.
Something like:

```
local a = {1,2,3,4}
setmetatable(a, {
  __index = function(t,i)
    local index = i%4
    index = index == 0 and 4 or index
    return t[index] end
})
for i = 1, 20 do print(a[i]) end
```